# Merton - Brownian Model

Tags: r

Quiero analizar 2 empresas mediante el modelo browniando geométrico.

Básicamente necesito ayuda sobre la prob. de default porque cuando pongo los valores de los activos, los pasivos, el `mu` y `desv. estandar` tengo dudas sobre si poner el numero completo (con todos los decimales y todos los millares). Esta duda surge porque he intentado modelar esto de varias formas y mis resultados finales son distintos.

¿Cual es la manera correcta?

```
cat("\f") 
rm(list = ls())

library("PerformanceAnalytics")
library("quantmod")

symbols <- c("BA")
getSymbols(symbols, from="2018-01-01", to="2018-12-31")
Price <- as.data.frame(BA$BA.Adjusted)
Returns.Boeing <- Return.calculate(Price, method="discrete")
Returns.Boeing <- Returns.Boeing[-1,]

#*Para poner el valor de los activos iniciales del periodo lo busqué en 
yahoo finance
#Al cierre del periodo 2018 los activos totales de la empresa fueron: USD. 117,359,000
######Activos totales:
Total.Assets = 117
######Mu: Retorno medio de un año. 
#Año 2018.
plot(t,V[1,],type="l",ylim=c(ymin, ymax), col=1, ylab="Value of 
Assets",xlab="time t")
for(i in 2:(nsim+1)){lines(t,V[i,], t="l",ylim=c(ymin, ymax),col=i)}
lines(t,rep(116,(M+1)), type = "l", lwd = 5)

#De las 500 simulaciones de montecarlo, solo 5 será default
x <- c(default_count, nsim - default_count)
lbs <- c("Default", "Survival")
pie(x, labels = lbs, main = "% Distribution of Defaults")

#Prob de default. En este caso es 1% y su prob de supervivencia es de 99%
x1 <- c(default_count, nsim - default_count)/nsim
```